# Understanding a PATCH request

Tags: rest, http, request, http-patch

The following is the structure of my content in MongoDB

```
{
  partnerName: "Zumba Fitness",
  supportedProducts: [
   "Fitness 1.0",
   "Protein Bars"
  ]
}
```

I want to modify/update the contents of **supportedProducts** upon a PATCH request. For example, I want to change **Fitness 1.0** to **Fitness 2.0**

I am unsure how the request for PATCH from the client side will look like. Would be it something as following

```
  PATCH /data/{partnerName}
  Content-Type: application/json

  [
    { op: "replace", path: "/supportedProducts", value: "Fitness 2.0" }
  ]
```

I have tried the above, but it did not modify the content in my database

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-6) says the media type for JSON Patch is

```
application/json-patch+json
```

> I have tried the above, but it did not modify the content in my database

I wouldn't expect that to happen by magic; you are still going to need to invoke code that will apply the patch.  For example: [jsonpatch-to-mongodb](https://github.com/mongodb-js/jsonpatch-to-mongodb)